# Is it possible to prove the content of a file hasn't changed since certain date?

Tags: hash

Today I make an archive file. Later I might want to send the archive file to somebody else, but when I send it, I want to be able to prove to the other person that I haven't changed anything in it after today. 
Knowing that computer- and serverdates may be spoofed, can I do anything myself to assure this? Like including something or anything.

I've been thinking about hashes, but that doesn't seem to fix the content in time. Only when I would have it registered at a notary, but that would be a bit oversized solution :-). And including the headlines of todays news would only prove it's NOT unaltered since yesterday.

Can this be done, or is there any objective reasoning why this would not be possible?

Comment: Cheapest and easiest is to send the hash today.  For the price of a postage stamp, you can mail the hash to yourself and get a dated postmark, if you don't want to send it to them... And there are several services, as well.

Comment: Similar questions with a similar solution (trusted timestamp): [Proving an action was done at an exact time - a posteriori](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101292/proving-an-action-was-done-at-an-exact-time-a-posteriori), [How to Prove you created IP using a Notary](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220247/how-to-prove-you-created-ip-using-a-notary).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thanks for the links, it was an answer on your second linked question that brought me to opentimestamps.org, that seems the most open and straightforward solution and with more background info than I can read right now. I can't accept the comment though. How am I supposed to give the right credits?

Comment: @PandaP: *"I can't accept the comment though. How am I supposed to give the right credits?"* -  Just give the credit to the actual answer which helped you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, yes I tried yesterday already, but by now I have enough credits for it to work. Thanks for your help, it was useful.

Answer (score 6):

While you cannot mathematically *prove* that a document was unchanged since a certain time, you can use a [Trusted Timestamp Service](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) to provide signed evidence that you haven’t tampered with it since the time you submitted it to be signed.